# Is $\sum\limits_{{\rm{i}} = 1}^{n - k} {{b_i}} \times {b_{n-2}} + b_{k}$ correct to express this pattern in base n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

having seen the pattern be,ow i have tried to express it in base n, of course there should be few constraints added to parameters.

$$\begin{align}
1 \times 8 + 1 &= 9\\
12 \times 8 + 2 &= 98\\
123 \times 8 + 3 &= 987\\
1234 \times 8 + 4 &= 9876\\
12345 \times 8 + 5 &= 98765\\
123456 \times 8 + 6 &= 987654\\
1234567 \times 8 + 7 &= 9876543\\
12345678 \times 8 + 8 &= 98765432\\
123456789 \times 8 + 9 &= 987654321\\
&\;\vdots\\
\sum\limits_{{\rm{i}} = 1}^{n - k} {{b_i}}  \times {b_{n-2}} + b_{k} &= {b_{n - 1}}{b_{n - 2}} \cdot  \cdot  \cdot {b_{n - k}}\\
\end{align}$$

$$$$where $ b_k $ is the kth symbol in base n.

my question is, is that correct? and what are some other ways that the above pattern can be expressed/generalised?

Comment: The way you have expressed it, these are not true. I think the first one is $+1$, second one is $+2$ and so on & then it kind of reverses.  Please correct the question

Comment: I don't know what you mean, can you please edit the question so I can see what you mean please?

Comment: Look at the second line... $12$ times $8$ is $96$. Add $1$ to it and you get $97$, and not $98$ as shown in your equation. Also when your doing times 6, it should be $123456$ x $8$ + $6$ = $987654$ and so on further

Comment: @Shailesh : thank you, fixed it now, I think

Comment: It is still not fixed. Please see the RHS. The digits should be in descending order.

Comment: @Shailesh : Thank you once again, I think finally it is fixed! Ihope